# Получить хэш крайнего коммита, на который ссылается тэг заданного формата и значение этого тэга

Tags: git, bash, git-bash

## Постановка задачи

Пишу скрипт для автоматизации работы с git. Скрипт пишется под оболочку bash.
Мне необходимо получить хэш крайнего коммита из истории *текущей* ветки, на который ссылается тэг формата `[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+` и значение этого тэга.

## Мои потуги

### Попытка 1

На первый взгляд, задачка показалась простой, т.к. команда `$ git log` выводит в консоль, вместе с хэшэм коммита, и все ссылки на него. Примерно так:

```
commit 1f2450076ffbc6f79efedf8a3b0537fa2a58fe03 (HEAD -> master, tag: 0.2.2, origin/master)
```

Как говориться, grep в руки и вперед. Написал вот такую команду:

```
git log | grep -E '^commit [^ ]{40}.*tag: [0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' | head -n 1
```

Подразумевалось, что на выходе я получу первую строку из лога, в которой есть хэш коммита и тэг нужного формата. Дальше добыть нужные значения это дело техники. Но результат не вывел ничего.

Как оказалось, при передаче вывода `git log` по конвейеру, обрезается часть строки, в которой перечислены ссылки на коммит. Для примера, команда `git log -1 | grep -E '^commit'`, вместо ожидаемого

```
commit 1f2450076ffbc6f79efedf8a3b0537fa2a58fe03 (HEAD -> master, tag: 0.2.2, origin/master)
```

, выводит

```
commit 1f2450076ffbc6f79efedf8a3b0537fa2a58fe03
```

### Попытки 2+

В результате гугления, проб и ошибок, перепробовал множество вариантов с `git show`, `git tag`, `git rev-list`, `git log`, `git for-each-ref` и т.д. Но каждое из решений имело свои недостатки: что-то выводит все тэги, в том числе и из других веток; что-то не позволяет отсортировать результат в соответствии с историей коммитов; кое-что вообще не из этой оперы. ))

В интернетах готовых решений тоже не нашел.

### Предположения

Конечно, можно получить список тэгов, с помощью цикла и `git show` сопоставить их с коммитами, после чего получить историю коммитов и, опять же в цикле, проверять на нужные мне условия. Но такое решение выглядит крайне монструозным, и очень не хочется решать задачу таким способом.

## P.S.

`git tag --sort=<key>`

Возлагал я надежды на эту опцию, но какие значения `<key>` допустимы, для меня остается загадкой. Если просветите и на этот счет, буду крайне признателен.

## P.S.S.

За правильный ответ принимается не только готовый код, но и наставление на путь истинный, которое позволит мне самому решить задачу лаконичным образом.

Comment: Посмотри на git describe

Comment: Похоже на правду, но есть ньюансы с glob(7) шаблоном.
`git describe master --tags --match=[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]* --long`
Вот эта команда будет выводить то, что нужно, пока в номере версии не появиться двузначное число.
Как указать в glob(7) шаблоне несколько повторений символа, наподобие регулярки `'[0-9]+'`, я как-то не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вообще список меток можно посмотреть командой *tag* (см. `$ man git-tag`):

```
$ git tag
```

ограничить этот список только теми метками, которые «достижимы» из указанной точки (например, `HEAD`):

```
$ git tag --merged HEAD
```

по поводу порядка: можно сортировать список, например, по полю `authordate`:

```
$ git tag --sort=authordate
```

в обратном порядке — добавьте `-` перед именем поля (список полей см. в `$ man git-for-each-ref`:

```
$ git tag --sort=-authordate
```

ну а дальше отобрать только подходящие под требующийся шаблон/маску и оставить только последнюю строку:

```
$ git tag --merged HEAD --sort=authordate | grep шаблон | tail -n 1
```